# Stored property without initial value prevents synthesized initializers

Tags: swift, properties, protocols

I declare a protocol:

```
 protocol FullNameable {
        var fullName: String {get set}
    }
```

then adopt the above protocol for class and struct like below:

```
struct LectureStruct: FullNameable {
    var fullName: String
}

class LectureClass: FullNameable {
    var fullName: String
}
```

But for class I am getting error - Stored property 'fullName' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers. Why this error is not for a struct?

Comment: The swift struct has default constructor including all undefined properties, class must have explicit constructor in such case (due to inheritance).

Answer (score 4):

According to swift [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html):

> All structures have an automatically generated memberwise initializer,
>   which you can use to initialize the member properties of new structure
>   instances. Initial values for the properties of the new instance can
>   be passed to the memberwise initializer by name

```
let vga = Resolution(width: 640, height: 480)
```

> Unlike structures, class instances don’t receive a default memberwise
>   initializer.

In your case, you can instantiate `LectureStruct` with:

```
let lecture = LectureStruct(fullName: "Match Lecture")
```

In order to do the same with `LectureClass` you'll need to define an init method like so:

```
class LectureClass: FullNameable {
    var fullName: String

    init(fullName: String) {
        self.fullName = fullName
    }
}
```